# How to add new field in existing document using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to add new field in a existing document but it can not add successfully.

Here is my code:

```
db.kf_users.update({"_id":ObjectId("573c5e4b55f5ab855473f23b")},
                   {$set:{"payment_status":0,
                          "feedback_privilages":"5736cdfbed8cda709ffc8912"}
                   });
```

When I am checking by running this `db.kf_users.find().pretty()`, I could get those new field in required document.

Comment: You need to find the exact document to see the changes `db.kf_users.find({"_id":ObjectId("573c5e4b55f5ab855473f23b")).pretty()`. All other document will have the old fields. That's why mongodb schema is sometimes called dynamic

Comment: You want to add the new fields to all the records or only one record, i.e. for `"_id":ObjectId("573c5e4b55f5ab855473f23b")` record only?

Comment: ok,now its coming.Thank you.